# Show Two Groups in Tableau Heat Maps

Tags: graph, charts, tableau-api, visualization, heatmap

I’m relatively new to Tableau and have a question.
I want to create a heatmap show the location of two different groups of people. I’ve learned how to overlay maps using dual axis but the problem I keep running into is that each group requires different filters to aggregate the data the way I want.
Basically, I want to show:
Group1.id IF charge_id IS NOT NULL
And
Group2.id IF status = ‘ACTIVE’
Whenever I create a calculated field with one of the above calculated fields and place it in the filters box it automatically removes the other group from the map because the filters contradict one and other.
Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The filter shelf applies to the entire worksheet, so if you want to “filter”  each field selectively, use an IF expression in a calculated field that evaluates to null when you don’t want that field in the view.

Give sample data if you want more detail